# What is the difference between {} and Object?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Recently, I'm confused about the difference between `{}` and `Object`. Sometimes, `{}` will solve my problem, sometimes, it can't and I switched with `Object`. I really don't know why.

I did some tests, hopefully, it can give you some hint.

```
const t: Array<{label: string}> = [{label:'1'}];
const arr: Array<{}> = t; //error
const arr2: Array<Object> = t; //pass
```

Comment: Minimize your example.

Comment: `{}` is an alias for `new Object()`

Answer (score 2):

`{}` is an alias for `new Object()`.

So you can say `Object` is a `class` and `{}` is an `instance` of that class.

You can see here:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Object()) == JSON.stringify({}))

console.log({} instanceof Object)
```

Comment: He is asking about flow types, not a javascript objects

Answer (score 2):

I think this answer is more reasonable [Github link:[mixed type] Supertype bug](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1644).

> Array are invariant in Flow

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
var bs: Array<B> = [];
var as: Array<A> = bs;
as.push(new A); // this would be bad!
```

> I assertion that `Array<B>` should be a subtype of `Array<A>` if `A` is a supertype of `A`,
>   **isn't true**.

And `Object` is an exception,

> The `Object` type is a `supertype` and `subtype` of all objects. That means `Object` is not the strict equivalent of the native/built-in Object type but is more similar to `any`.

@Tushar Acharekar and @Ayush Gupta,  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used [Flow](https://flow.org/) but I tried your code on here: https://flow.org/try/, and I get this message: `Type argument 'T' is incompatible`. And then it adds the variable `Property 'label' is incompatible` and `Property not found`.

I'm guessing because `t` is an array of [Sealed Objects](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-sealed-objects), but `arr` is an array of [Unsealed Objects](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-unsealed-objects).

Now it works when you assign `t` to `arr2` because `arr2` is just an array of (plain Javascript) objects. You can assign an array of unsealed objects to `arr2` also. Or push to `arr2` a mixed of sealed and unsealed objects.

Note that these passes:

```
const t: Array<{label: string}> = [{label:'1'}];
const t1: {label: string} = {label: `1`};
const w: Array<{label: string}> = [t1];
const t2: {label: string} = {label: `2`};
w.push(t2);
```

But this will *not* pass:

```
let w: Array<{label: string}> = [];
const t3: {} = {};
w.push(t3);
```

But these will pass:

```
const u: Array<Object> = [{label:'1'}];
const arr: Array<{}> = u;   

const v: Array<{}> = [{label:'1'}];
const arr2: Array<Object> = v;  

const t3: {foo: number} = {foo:1};
arr2.push(t3);
```

Answer (score 0):

An object is a collection of properties, and a property is an association between a name (or key) and a value. A property's value can be a function, in which case the property is known as a method.

- I prefer to use `{}` in case of generating `key:value` paire data.
- I prefer to use `new Object()` to create complex object like `Method1, Method2`

Please see below example

```
var d = new Object();           //This is the simplest way to create an empty object.
var a = Object.create(null);    //This method creates a new object extending the prototype object passed as a parameter.
var b = {};                     //This is equivalent to Object.create(null) method, using a null prototype as an argument.
```

**Method 1:**

```
var Animal = {
  type: 'Invertebrates',  // Default value of properties
  displayType: function() {  // Method which will display type of Animal
    console.log(this.type);
  }
};
var animalObject = Object.create(Animal);
animalObject.displayType();         // Output:Invertebrates
var fish = Object.create(Animal);
fish.type = 'Fishes';
fish.displayType();                 // Output:Fishes
```

**Method 2:**

```
var Obj = function(name) {
  this.name = name
}
var c = new Obj("hello");
```

> [Dicoverign Javascript](https://youtu.be/ZUHyZHwZtUY) is best video to learn `javascript
>   prototype`

Comment: He is asking about flow types, not a javascript objects

Comment: @AlekseyL. i aware about that, owner has changed his context of question, but according to title i try to explain usages-difference in `{}` & `Object`